# Migrating WordPress 404 Error

Tags: wordpress, migration, http-status-code-404

I am migrating my site to a new server with a new domain. The front page loads fine, but any other link causes a 404 error. What could cause this??? A permalink issue??

This is what I have done:

- Moved all files to the new server
- Searched and replaced my database for old-domain.com with new-domain.com
- backed up and upload to the new server my SQL database
- Changed wp-config.php according to the new database

What else could it be? I even tried using Search-Replace-DB-master to search and replace in case of any serialized data and no avail. I can't even get to /wp-admin to do any reconfiguration.

Comment: Have you tried changing the permalink options?

Comment: I cant get to it. No dashboard access... I get the 404 error.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, problem solved.

Solution:

The issue was indeed a permalink issue. To solve this I accessed phpMyAdmin, searched my wordpress database for 'permalink' and found entries in the table 'options'. You have edit the field 'permalink_structure' and leave it blank. In my case I had the value of '/%postname%/' for permalink_structure. Save it and try loading your website. Whalaa!

FYI, if you still have issues accessing wp-admin (like me) it is likely to be a security plugin you have installed. Access your server (SSH or FTP) and rename your plugin directory so WordPress will not load it. A reminder, plugins are at /wp-content/plugins.

Good luck.

Comment: This solution seems to be good, but it does not really solve the issue. Having this `  28 | permalink_structure | /%postname%/ | yes ` in your `wp_options` means that your permalink is set to **post name**, leaving it blank as suggested here means set it to **simple**.

Comment: you're right @bam, it resets the permalink structure to its default value. It's been too long for me to remember, I think I lost access to the entire site because of the permalink structure couldn't be recognized. I cleared it in the database and WordPress reset it to default, then I gained access to the site again and set it back to post_name.

Answer (score 1):

Following my comment above, I think this is the solution for this issue:

**Edit apache2.conf**

`sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`. Scroll down until you find `Directory /var/www/>`. Change `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`. Save the file and quit (`Ctrl + X` and `Y`).

**Enable mod_rewrite for .htaccess**

`sudo a2enmod rewrite`

**Restart the server**

`sudo systemctl restart apache2`

This is what worked for me and hope it'll work for you too.

Credit: [Avinash](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14685/after-server-migration-only-the-homepage-works) on WordPress stackexchange

Comment: Works for me using sudo a2enmod rewrite command. Thanks